# Getting a reference to the last item of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I can use the following to get the value of the last item of `$array`. How can I get a reference to that item?

```
$last_item = end($array);
```

The items of `$array` are indexed arrays.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php#24804

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
end($array);
$referenceToLastElement = &$array[key($array)];
```

Comment: That's interesting. I wonder if it would perform better compared to the approach in the accepted answer.

Comment: @EmanuilRusev: It would perform better since it would work correctly on any array.

Comment: Is this faster than count() method?

Comment: The count method won't work with anything but clean, consecutively-numbered, enumerated arrays.... speed difference (if any) is likely to be measured in nano-seconds; but as there's no arithmetic involved in this method, it's probably the more performant approach

Comment: Actually, non-consecutively-numbered objects are not correctly "arrays." They are objects. They look much the same in PHP, but they are represented differently, which representation is most important when they get sent over AJAX.

Answer (score 3):

`count()` will give you the length of the array, which you can apply some simple arithmetic to to get a reference to the last element of the array:

```
$array = array(
  array('jkl' => '456'),
  array('abc' => '456'),
);
print_r($array);
$last_item = &$array[count($array) - 1];
$last_item['abc'] = '123';
print_r($array);
```

Comment: That's the kind of an answer I was hoping for.

Comment: This will only work if the array is indexed with an unbroken integer sequence starting from 0 -- a big "if".

Comment: @Jon - If that's a possibility definitely use Mark's answer. Actually I like Mark's answer more than my own - it's much more elegant and flexible solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
list($last_key,$last_value) = each(array_slice($array,-1,1,true));
```

---

Attempt number 2?

```
$last_item = &$array[array_pop(array_keys($array))];
```

That gives you a variable reference to the last element of the array.

Comment: I don't get it. I don't need neither the key of the last element, nor its value - just a reference.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "just a reference". I'll have another try. See the edit.